# How to position button within column next to input file in Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in Bootstrap 3 that has 3 inputs per row. I need to position a delete row button (which is an anchor element with class btn btn-danger) but I cannot position the anchor button next to (on the right side of) the input file element in the last column. The button is positioned below of the input. Please any help it will be gratefull

```js
/* inicio del bloque que agrega una fila a la tabla */
     
     var conteo = 1;
     $("#add_row").click(function() {
      
   if(conteo<10 ||   $('.ruttabl1').length < 10) {
            
$('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(conteo)+'"></tr>');
$('#addr'+conteo).html("<td class='order'>"+ (conteo) +"</td> <td>  <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-12'> <input name='nombres_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' placeholder='Ingrese nombre completo' class='form-control txtVal' required><span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-10'> <input name='ruts_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' maxlength='12' placeholder='Ingrese RUT' class='form-control ruttabl1' required> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-11'><input type='file' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+"' name='archivo_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' required> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+1+"'></span> <a class='btn-remove-tr btn btn-danger' style='float:left'>Delete row</a>  <div id='errorBlock"+conteo+"' class='help-block'></div>  <span id='fileErrorValidMsg"+conteo+"' class='file-val-error'></span><br><span style='color:red'></span> </div> </td>"); 
                          
   conteo++;
            
  /* inicio actualizacion numeros de filas */ 
   if($('#tab_logic tr').length > 1) {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      $('#tab_logic td.order').text(function (i) {  return i + 1; });
                     }
  /* fin actualizacion numeros de fila */
                     
       }
 
   
    });
    
/* cierre del bloque que agrega una fila a la tabla */

  /* inicio bloque de eliminación de fila de la tabla */

     
        var i = $('#tab_logic tr').length;
        $('#tab_logic').on('click', '.btn-remove-tr', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
                
        if($('#tab_logic tr').length>1) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            $('td.order').text(function (i) {
                return i + 1;
            });
        }
        
        if($('#tab_logic tr').length<10) { $('#add_row').show();  }
        return false;
        });
  /* fin bloque de eliminación de fila de la tabla */
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- inicio tabla  -->
                                

   <div class="row clearfix ">
    
      
           <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <label class="control-label"><p><small>5. Nombre(s) y RUTs y Archivos (*)</small></p></label>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sm" id="tab_logic" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                   
                    <thead class="thead-inverse bg-primary">
                        <tr class="cabecera">
                            <th class="text-center"><p>#</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center"><p>Nombre Completo (*)</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center"><p>RUT (*)</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                            <p>
                                Adjuntar documento (*)
                                </p>
                            </th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                    <tr id="addr0">
                        <td class="order">
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-12">
                              <input type="text"  id="nombre_s1t1_0" name="nombres_s1t1_array[0]" placeholder="Ingrese nombre completo" class="form-control" required>
                              <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="nombre_s1t1_01"></span>
                          </div>
                        </td>

                     
                        <td>
                      
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" name="ruts_s1t1_array[0]" id="rut_s1t1_0" placeholder="Ingrese RUT" maxlength="12" class="form-control ruttabl1" required>  

                            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="rut_s1t1_01"></span> 

                      
                              </div>     
                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-11">
                              <input type="file" id="archivo_s1t1_array0" name="archivo_s1t1_array[0]" required>

                              <div id="errorBlock0" class="help-block"></div>
                              <span id="fileErrorValidMsg0" class="file-val-error"></span>
                          
                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                  
                                       
                </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
                   
                               
        <div style="float:right">
          <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary addnewrow pull-left">Agregar fila
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </a> 
        </div>


        </br> </br>
<!-- fin tabla -->
```

Comment: try my code, may be this will help you, i have updated your code with some css

Answer (score 0):

The file input field need to use `display:inline-block` and need to remove the button style `float:left;`. Also, I suggest you to build a html code template rather than paste html code in javascript which is hard for maintain.

```
/* inicio del bloque que agrega una fila a la tabla */

     var conteo = 1;
     $("#add_row").click(function() {

   if(conteo<10 ||   $('.ruttabl1').length < 10) {

$('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(conteo)+'"></tr>');
$('#addr'+conteo).html("<td class='order'>"+ (conteo) +"</td> <td>  <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-12'> <input name='nombres_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' placeholder='Ingrese nombre completo' class='form-control txtVal' required><span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-10'> <input name='ruts_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' maxlength='12' placeholder='Ingrese RUT' class='form-control ruttabl1' required style='display:inline-block;'> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-11'><input type='file' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+"' name='archivo_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' required> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+1+"'></span> <a class='btn-remove-tr btn btn-danger' >Delete row</a>  <div id='errorBlock"+conteo+"' class='help-block'></div>  <span id='fileErrorValidMsg"+conteo+"' class='file-val-error'></span><br><span style='color:red'></span> </div> </td>"); 

   conteo++;
```

Answer (score 0):

i just updated css as per your requirement, try this may be this will help you.

```js
/* inicio del bloque que agrega una fila a la tabla */
     
     var conteo = 1;
     $("#add_row").click(function() {
      
   if(conteo<10 ||   $('.ruttabl1').length < 10) {
            
$('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(conteo)+'"></tr>');
$('#addr'+conteo).html("<td class='order'>"+ (conteo) +"</td> <td>  <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-12'> <input name='nombres_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' placeholder='Ingrese nombre completo' class='form-control txtVal' required><span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-10'> <input name='ruts_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' maxlength='12' placeholder='Ingrese RUT' class='form-control ruttabl1' required> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td class='browse-btn-td'> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-12'><div style='float:left;'><input type='file' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+"' name='archivo_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' required> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+1+"'></span></div><div style='float:right'> <a class='btn-remove-tr btn btn-danger' style='float:left'>Delete row</a></div><div style='clear:both;'></div>  <div id='errorBlock"+conteo+"' class='help-block'></div>  <span id='fileErrorValidMsg"+conteo+"' class='file-val-error'></span><br><span style='color:red'></span> </div> </td>"); 
                          
   conteo++;
            
  /* inicio actualizacion numeros de filas */ 
   if($('#tab_logic tr').length > 1) {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      $('#tab_logic td.order').text(function (i) {  return i + 1; });
                     }
  /* fin actualizacion numeros de fila */
                     
       }
 
   
    });
    
/* cierre del bloque que agrega una fila a la tabla */

  /* inicio bloque de eliminación de fila de la tabla */

     
        var i = $('#tab_logic tr').length;
        $('#tab_logic').on('click', '.btn-remove-tr', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
                
        if($('#tab_logic tr').length>1) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            $('td.order').text(function (i) {
                return i + 1;
            });
        }
        
        if($('#tab_logic tr').length<10) { $('#add_row').show();  }
        return false;
        });
  /* fin bloque de eliminación de fila de la tabla */
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: block;
    width: 188px;
}
.browse-btn-td{
  width:56%;
}
.has-feedback .form-control {
  padding:0 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- inicio tabla  -->
                                

   <div class="row clearfix ">
    
      
           <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <label class="control-label"><p><small>5. Nombre(s) y RUTs y Archivos (*)</small></p></label>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sm" id="tab_logic" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                   
                    <thead class="thead-inverse bg-primary">
                        <tr class="cabecera">
                            <th class="text-center"><p>#</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center"><p>Nombre Completo (*)</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center"><p>RUT (*)</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                            <p>
                                Adjuntar documento (*)
                                </p>
                            </th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                    <tr id="addr0">
                        <td class="order">
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-12">
                              <input type="text"  id="nombre_s1t1_0" name="nombres_s1t1_array[0]" placeholder="Ingrese nombre completo" class="form-control" required>
                              <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="nombre_s1t1_01"></span>
                          </div>
                        </td>

                     
                        <td>
                      
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" name="ruts_s1t1_array[0]" id="rut_s1t1_0" placeholder="Ingrese RUT" maxlength="12" class="form-control ruttabl1" required>  

                            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="rut_s1t1_01"></span> 

                      
                              </div>     
                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-11">
                              <input type="file" id="archivo_s1t1_array0" name="archivo_s1t1_array[0]" required>

                              <div id="errorBlock0" class="help-block"></div>
                              <span id="fileErrorValidMsg0" class="file-val-error"></span>
                          
                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                  
                                       
                </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
                   
                               
        <div style="float:right">
          <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary addnewrow pull-left">Agregar fila
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </a> 
        </div>


        </br> </br>
<!-- fin tabla -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing to do apply the class to that tag with following css:

```
.cls-nm{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
}
```

This is the right thing to do the task